# 【R】How can I interpret the fixed effects of multiple combined variables using "feols" function in "fixest" package?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I am now doing regression by using "fixest" package in R. Especially, "feols" function. I do so by incorporating mutltipled comibined variables as a fixed effect. Examples are below;

`est <-  feols(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | a, b^c, data)`

and I try to plot results by running;

`plot(fixef(est))`

and I can surely get figures. But the probelm is I cannot interpret the results of "b^c"'s fixed effects because the labels in the plot are unable to interpret. For example, some labels are showing "34" or "57", which look irrelevant to original variables "b" or "c".

How can I interpret the results? Or, in the example above, how can I tell which combination of "b" and "c" "34" is made of?